# How to print the results of an array in a single line?

Tags: java

I would like to know if anybody could help me to understand why my array result does not come in one single line. The results of the code below is printed as:

```
[
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
]
```

Instead of `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]`.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong to the results not come in on line?

```
class RangeClass {

    int[] makeRange(int lower, int upper) {
      int arr[] = new int[ (upper - lower) + 1 ];

      for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = lower++;
      }
      return arr;
    }

    public static void main(String arguments[]) {
    int theArray[];
    RangeClass theRange = new RangeClass();

    theArray = theRange.makeRange(1, 10);
    System.out.println("The array: [ ");
    for(int i = 0; i< theArray.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(" " + theArray[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("]");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow!

Comment: Use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println`.

Comment: If you want everything on one line, use `print`, instead of `println`

Comment: Thanks Guys i should have used print instead of println:)

Answer (score 51):

You can use shorter version:

```
int theArray[] = {1, 2, 3};
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(theArray));
```

Comment: java.util.Arrays.toString(theArray)

Comment: I believe the larger ask is to see how this can be acheived programtically without using the Arrays.toString helper library?

Answer (score 6):

Replace `System.out.println` by `System.out.print` like this:

```
System.out.print("The array: [ ");
for(int i = 0; i< theArray.length; i++) {
  System.out.print(" " + theArray[i] + " ");
}
System.out.println("]");
```

`println` add a line separator at the end of what you just printed.

Comment: The first `println` should also be replaced with `print`.

Comment: Thanks for helping it worked. I am new on Java programing and I did not realized that there was another form to print result. Thanks again for the support.

Comment: @CleitonLima If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in one line using **[Java 8](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-foreach-examples/)**

Assume you have this list of integers

```
List<Integer> lst = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9);
```

You can print all the items in one shot in this way

```
lst.forEach(nb -> System.out.print(nb + " "));
```

Or in this way

```
lst.forEach(System.out::print);
```

Result

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 4):

Use System.out.print instead of System.out.println

Answer (score 4):

int []arr = {3, 4, 1, 7, 8, 5, 4, 11, 33, 21, 17, 15};

System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arr).replace("[","").replace("]", "").replace(",", ""));

Answer (score 2):

Just make one small change to your code:

```
class ArrayDemo {

  int[] makeRange(int lower, int upper) {
    int arr[] = new int[ (upper - lower) + 1 ];

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i] = lower++;
    }
    return arr;
  }

  public static void main(String arguments[]) {
    int theArray[];
    ArrayDemo theRange = new ArrayDemo();

    theArray = theRange.makeRange(1, 10);
    System.out.print("The array: [ ");  //Remove println here
    for(int i = 0; i< theArray.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(" " + theArray[i] + " "); //Same here
    }
    System.out.println("]");
  }
}
```

Output array: `[  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 ]`

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < theArray.length;i++){
 if(i==0)
   System.out.print("["+theArray[i]);
 else if(i==theArray.length-1)
   System.out.print(","+theArray[i]+"]");
 else
   System.out.print(","+theArray[i]);
}
```

Output :(for example)

> [1,2,5,3,7]

Answer (score 0):

**System.out.println** changes the line after printing the statement. That is why, your array elements are not coming in one line.
Try using `System.out.print` instead and that would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use System.out.print() at the place of System.out.println() in all the code because
if you use System.out.println() a new line character is getting printed after our output on console each time it is called but if you use System.out.print() it will print what you are passing it as parameter.
So Change your code to

```
class RangeClass {
    int[] makeRange(int lower, int upper) {
        int arr[] = new int[ (upper - lower) + 1 ];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = lower++;
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void main(String arguments[]) {
        int theArray[];
        RangeClass theRange = new RangeClass();

        theArray = theRange.makeRange(1, 10);
        System.out.print("The array: [ ");
        for(int i = 0; i< theArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + theArray[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("]");
    }
}
```